# Comparing an array against itself

Tags: php

I am currently a bit stuck in finding out how to compare these variables against eachother, I have 24 dropdown selections with 24 options to choose from within each one, I then post them to the PHP page. What is the easiest, most efficient way of comparing each of these values against each other to check that each option that is chose is different from each other as none of the 24 options can be the same. I know that an array is the way forward with this, just not sure on how to compare them.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
    $id = $_POST[trackid];
    $pos1 = $_POST[pos1];
    $pos2 = $_POST[pos2];
    $pos3 = $_POST[pos3];
    $pos4 = $_POST[pos4];
    $pos5 = $_POST[pos5];
    $pos6 = $_POST[pos6];
    $pos7 = $_POST[pos7];
    $pos8 = $_POST[pos8];
    $pos9 = $_POST[pos9];
    $pos10 = $_POST[pos10];
    $pos11 = $_POST[pos11];
    $pos12 = $_POST[pos12];
    $pos13 = $_POST[pos13];
    $pos14 = $_POST[pos14];
    $pos15 = $_POST[pos15];
    $pos16 = $_POST[pos16];
    $pos17 = $_POST[pos17];
    $pos18 = $_POST[pos18];
    $pos19 = $_POST[pos19];
    $pos20 = $_POST[pos20];
    $pos21 = $_POST[pos21];
    $pos22 = $_POST[pos22];
    $pos23 = $_POST[pos23];
    $pos24 = $_POST[pos24];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do an array_unique on it. First you'll need to put those POST vars into an array instead of splitting them up.

```
$pos = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++)
{
    $pos["pos$i"] = $_POST["pos$i"];
}

$unique = array_unique($pos);
if (count($unique) == 24)
{
    // all good!
}
else
{
    // bad!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given an array you could try [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function

```
count($original_array) != count(array_unique($original_array))
```

Alternative solution with [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
count(array_count_values($original_array)) = count($original_array)
```

There are lot of way to do that (e.g. a for loop), it just depends from your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should be adding quotes around your array indices rather than using barewords which should be raising warnings:

```
$pos1 = $_POST['pos1'];
```

To copy the `pos*` values out of `$_POST`, you should use a loop:

```
$pos = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; ++$i) {
  $pos["pos$i"] = $_POST["pos$i"];
}
```

To make sure there are no duplicates, use `array_unique` and see if the two arrays have the same length:

```
if (count(array_unique($pos)) == count($pos)) {
  # pos contains no duplicates
}
```

Comment: Genuine question: is `$post["pos#{i}"]` a valid PHP variable variable syntax? I have never seen it documented anywhere, I always do `$post["pos{$i}"]`

Comment: @Dave Err, no. Thanks for catching that. I was thinking in Ruby. Fixed for PHP interpolation syntax.

Answer (score 0):

can you more explicit? if none of them can be the same, than what is the problem?

considering that you actually can select the same option more than once or you just want to protect from attacks, than you can put them into an array, and then use the [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function.